# I can connect to AWS Neptune using Postman, but not using AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-neptune

Using AWS Lambda (with the correct permissions and roles) I can't query it, as it returns the following error:

**ConnectionError:** HTTPSConnectionPool(host='XXXX', port=YYYY): Max retries exceeded with url: /gremlin (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at ZZZZ>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

I tried using Postman on a mid server I can query the Neptune database successfully.

Comment: Is your Lambda function configured to run in the same VPC as the Neptune cluster?  Are the security groups for both the Neptune cluster/instances and Lambda function configured correctly to allow traffic from the Lambda function?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly it @TaylorRiggan, thank you for your quick response. Now I'm having trouble connecting to a regional API, since the security rules are restricting connections. Do you have any thoughts on that?

Comment: Can you provide some more context on the regional API that you're attempting to use?

Comment: Sure, I need to retrieve information from a regional API set up in API Gateway as regional (public), and store that information in Amazon Neptune. The problem is that since the Lambda is inside restrictive security groups, it doesn't allow connecting with public APIs.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you looking to front this lambda function with an API gateway?  Or does the lambda function, itself, need to access an API hosted with API gateway?

Comment: The second option, the Lambda needs access to an API hosted in API gateway as regional.

Comment: You'll need an VPC Interface Endpoint to allow traffic to be routed from within the VPC out to the public API Gateway regional endpoint: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html#apigateway-private-api-create-interface-vpc-endpoint